# Why ADL does not resolve to the correct function with std::get

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, structured-bindings

I am trying to code a template function that uses an ADL resolved `get` to fetch members of a struct/range (`tuple`-esque).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

int main() {
    auto tup = std::make_tuple(1, 2);
    std::cout << get<0>(tup) << std::endl;
}
```

I am doing this because of what the structured bindings proposal (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf  §11.5.3) says about how `get` is used to fetch elements from the struct.  It says that a non member `get` is used to fetch elements from within the struct.

I assumed that the code above would compile, because ADL would cause the `get` function to be looked for in the `std` namespace (because it's argument is of type `std::tuple<int, int>`, which is in `std`), where it would be found.  But, I get an error.  Can someone explain the right approach here and also why the code above does not work?  How can one force ADL to happen in this case?

Comment: Note that [since C++20 ADL works also for a call to template function with explicit template arguments and the code compiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493829/why-adl-does-not-resolve-to-the-correct-function-with-stdget/63830746#63830746).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem ultimately is templates:

```
std::cout << get<0>(tup) << std::endl;
//           ~~~~
```

At that point, the compiler doesn't know that this is a function that needs to be looked up using ADL yet - `get` is just a name. And since that name by itself doesn't find anything, this is going to be interpreted as an unknown name followed by less-than. To get this to work, you need some other function template `get` visible:

```
using std::get;
std::cout << get<0>(tup) << std::endl; // now, OK
```

Even if it does nothing:

```
template <class T> void get();

int main() {
    auto tup = std::make_tuple(1, 2); 
    std::cout << get<0>(tup) << std::endl;
}
```

The structured binding wording explicitly looks up `get` using argument-dependent lookup, so it avoids the need to have an already-visible function template named `get`, from [dcl.struct.bind]:

> The *unqualified-id* `get` is looked up in the scope of `E` by class member access lookup, and if that finds at least one declaration, the initializer is `e.get<i>()`. Otherwise, the initializer is `get<i>(e)`, where `get` is looked up in the associated namespaces. In either case, `get<i>` is interpreted as a *template-id*. [ Note: Ordinary unqualified lookup is not performed. — end note ]

The note is the key. If we had performed unqualified lookup, we'd just fail.

Comment: Very interesting!  I wonder though, does introducing this undefined function potentially cause any other problems?  Like conflicts or the like?

Comment: @Curious It would if it ended up being preferred. I mean, don't actually do that - I just put it there for explanatory purposes.

Comment: hmmm, is there any way I can force ADL to happen?  I tried the `template` keyword but of course that does not work..

Comment: @Curious Outside of structured bindings, nope. Also, I swear there was a language proposal to make this just work but I can't find.

Comment: @Barry, it is probably Robert Haberlach's D0389R1 that you remebered, but it was replaced with [p0846r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0846r0.html) which was accepted into C++20, which now [makes the OP's code valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493829/why-adl-does-not-resolve-to-the-correct-function-with-stdget/63830746#63830746)

Answer (score 12):

Argument Dependent Lookup doesn't work the same way [for function templates where an explicit template argument is given](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl#Notes).

> Although a function call can be resolved through ADL even if ordinary
>   lookup finds nothing, a function call to a function template with
>   explicitly-specified template arguments requires that there is a
>   declaration of the template found by ordinary lookup (otherwise, it is
>   a syntax error to encounter an unknown name followed by a less-than
>   character)

Basically, there needs to be some way for the unqualified lookup to find a template function. Then, the ADL can kick in (because the name `get` is then known to be a template). Cppreference gives an example:

> ```
> namespace N1 {
>   struct S {};
>   template<int X> void f(S);
> }
> namespace N2 {
>   template<class T> void f(T t);
> }
> void g(N1::S s) {
>   f<3>(s);      // Syntax error (unqualified lookup finds no f)
>   N1::f<3>(s);  // OK, qualified lookup finds the template 'f'
>   N2::f<3>(s);  // Error: N2::f does not take a non-type parameter
>                 //        N1::f is not looked up because ADL only works
>                 //              with unqualified names
>   using N2::f;
>   f<3>(s); // OK: Unqualified lookup now finds N2::f
>            //     then ADL kicks in because this name is unqualified
>            //     and finds N1::f
> }
> ```

Structured bindings are a special case, with ADL enabled.

> In the following contexts ADL-only lookup (that is, lookup in
>   associated namespaces only) takes place:
>
> - the lookup of non-member functions begin and end performed by the range-for loop if member lookup fails
> - the dependent name lookup from the point of template instantiation.
> - **the lookup of non-member function get performed by structured binding declaration for tuple-like types**

<sup>Emphasis added</sup>

Comment: Would it work to say `std::cout << template get<0>(tup) << '\n'`, or does a disambiguating `template` not work there for some reason?

Comment: @DanielH That sounds like it *could* work if someone proposed it. It [doesn't work at the moment](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dmG6fVeDQwzHvl6q)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I want to accept both answers but since the other answer includes a straightforward example of a simple resolution technique.  I am going to accept that.

Answer (score 2):

### Fast forward to C++20

[p0846r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0846r0.html) that was accepted into C++20 now allows ADL for a call to template function with explicit template arguments.

So the OP's code [now compiles as is with C++20](https://godbolt.org/z/xq885W) without an error!